# Python sum on keys for List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sum dict elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490738/how-to-sum-dict-elements)

I have a list of dictionaries as following:

```
[{'Name': 'A', 'amt':100},
 {'Name': 'B', 'amt':200},
 {'Name': 'A', 'amt':300},
 {'Name': 'C', 'amt':400},
 {'Name': 'C', 'amt':500},
 {'Name': 'A', 'amt':600}]
```

I want to sum `amt` for each `name` and get following result in list of dict:

```
 [{'Name':'A', 'amt':1000},
  {'Name':'B', 'amt':200},
  {'Name':'C', 'amt':900}]
```

Comment: have you done anything (anything at all)? or is this another case of a "make my code" question?

Comment: If it is a duplicate, it would be nice if you gave the link to the duplicate question rather than just marking it as a duplicate

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int)
for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    c[d['Name']] += d['amt']
```

It produces `c`:

```
{'A': 1000, 'C': 900, 'B': 200}
```

To convert it to list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Name': name, 'amt': amt} for name, amt in c.items()]
```

Result:

```
[{'Name': 'A', 'amt': 1000}, {'Name': 'C', 'amt': 900}, {'Name': 'B', 'amt':200}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution, this time using itertools:

```
lst = [
{'Name': 'A', 'amt':100},
{'Name': 'B', 'amt':200},
{'Name': 'A', 'amt':300},
{'Name': 'C', 'amt':400},
{'Name': 'C', 'amt':500},
{'Name': 'A', 'amt':600}]

import itertools as it
keyfunc = lambda x: x['Name']

groups = it.groupby(sorted(lst, key=keyfunc), keyfunc)
[{'Name':k, 'amt':sum(x['amt'] for x in g)} for k, g in groups]
```

Comment: I think this answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: As Martjin Pieters once said to me, using `sorted` with `itertools.groupby` allows a one-liner, but introduces some more complexity/CPU consumption because of the extra `sort`

Answer (score 2):

```
output_dict = {}
for i in dict_list:
    if i['Name'] in output_dict:
        output_dict[i['Name']] = i['amt']
    else:
        output_dict[i['Name']] += i['amt']
```

Will give you a dictionary where the keys are names and amounts are values. If you must have it as a list of dicts:

```
[{'Name':key, 'amt':value} for key, value in output_dict.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Example solution

I am not sure it is "*beautiful/Pythonic enough*", but it **is surely short and works without additional modules**:

```
def get_amt(name):
    return lambda x: x['amt'] if x['Name']==name else 0

names = sorted(set(map(lambda x: x['Name'], data)))
result = [{'Name':name,'amt':sum(map(get_amt(name), data))} for name in names]
```

### Proof

Proof is here: http://codepad.org/L1gcTpVK

If you supply `data` as in the question, the `result` will be equal to this:

> [{'Name': 'A', 'amt': 1000}, {'Name': 'B', 'amt': 200}, {'Name': 'C', 'amt': 900}]

which is **exactly as requested** :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def sum(dict_list):
    result_list = []
    name_dict = {}
    for dict_item in dict_list:
        name = dict_item['Name']
        amt = dict_item['amt']
        if name_dict.has_key(name):
            pos = name_dict[name]
            result_list[pos] = {'Name':name, 'amt': (result_list[pos]['amt']+amt)}
        else:
            result_list.append(dict_item)
            name_dict[name] = len(result_list) - 1
    return result_list
```

Comment: This worked for me almost as is. Thanks