# Fastest way to merge n-dictionaries and add values on 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to combine into one dictionary and add the values from each dictionary in the list. For example:

```
ds = [{1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}, {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 5}]
```

The final results should be a single dictionary:

```
merged = {1: 6, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 5}
```

I'm interested in performance and am looking for the fastest implementation that can merge a list of n-dictionaries into one dictionary and sum the values. An obvious implementation is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(int)

for d in ds:
    for k, v in d.items():
        merged[k] += v
```

Is there a faster way to do this in Python 2.6?

Comment: nvm this isn't a duplicate since this only allows 2.6

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490738/how-to-sum-dict-elements

Comment: @user1728853 How big will each dictionary be on average?

Comment: Fairly small, less than 500 items usually.

Comment: Nothing I could come up with is faster than your obvious implementation.

Comment: @user1728853 If you know the upper bound of the numbers possibly initializing a list with `[0]*n` could be faster. Also you might wanna try `.iteritems` to see if it helps for your case, I know it would for very huge data but not sure for `500` items if that's big enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`defaultdict` is still fastest, I found a few ways to speed it up by caching function names and now just found another way that sped it up significantly, by just iterating `for k in d` instead of using `d.items()` or `d.iteritems()`

Some timings so far:

```
from random import randrange
ds = [dict((randrange(1, 1000), randrange(1, 1000)) for i in xrange(500))
      for i in xrange(10000)]

# 10000 dictionaries of approx. length 500

from collections import defaultdict

def merge1(dicts, defaultdict=defaultdict, int=int):
    merged = defaultdict(int)
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            merged[k] += d[k]
    return merged

def merge2(dicts):
    merged = {}
    merged_get = merged.get
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            merged[k] = merged_get(k, 0) + d[k]
    return merged


def merge3(dicts):
    merged = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            merged[k] = merged[k] + d[k] if k in merged else 0
    return merged


from timeit import timeit
for func in ('merge1', 'merge2', 'merge3'):
    print func, timeit(stmt='{0}(ds)'.format(func),
                       setup='from __main__ import merge1, merge2, merge3, ds',
                       number=1)
```

---

```
merge1 0.992541510164
merge2 1.40478747997
merge3 1.23502204889
```

Comment: Are you sure that's actually faster, though?  (I ask because in the past, I've found summing Counter objects surprisingly slow.)

Comment: @DSM it doesn't matter it's a duplicate though, I think timings are in the other thread

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am on Python 2.6

Comment: @user1728853 Yeah you probably need to try both solutions with those optimizations, anyway that other thread already has the timings