# How to aggregate particular property value that is group by a particular property in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list which represent the item purchase of a customer:

```
purchases = [
   { 
       'id': 1, 'product': 'Item 1', 'price': 12.4, 'qty' : 4
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 1, 'product': 'Item 1', 'price': 12.4, 'qty' : 8
   },
   { 
       'id': 2, 'product': 'Item 2', 'price': 7.5, 'qty': 10
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 3, 'product': 'Item 3', 'price': 18, 'qty': 7
   }
]
```

Now i want the output that returns the distinct `product` with an aggregated qty.

```
result = [
   { 
       'id': 1, 'product': 'Item 1', 'price': 12.4, 'qty' : 12 # 8 + 4
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 2, 'product': 'Item 2', 'price': 7.5, 'qty': 10
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 3, 'product': 'Item 3', 'price': 18, 'qty': 7
   }
]
```

And the answers here never makes sense to me
[How to sum dict elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490738/how-to-sum-dict-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) it is simple - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html), last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(purchases)
print (df)
   id  price product  qty
0   1   12.4  Item 1    4
1   1   12.4  Item 1    8
2   2    7.5  Item 2   10
3   3   18.0  Item 3    7

print (df.groupby('product', as_index=False)
         .agg({'id':'first','price':'first','qty':'sum'})
         .to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'qty': 12, 'product': 'Item 1', 'price': 12.4, 'id': 1}, 
 {'qty': 10, 'product': 'Item 2', 'price': 7.5, 'id': 2}, 
 {'qty': 7, 'product': 'Item 3', 'price': 18.0, 'id': 3}]
```

If is possible groupby by 3 elements:

```
print (df.groupby(['id','product', 'price'], as_index=False)['qty'].sum()
         .to_dict(orient='records'))
[{'qty': 12, 'product': 'Item 1', 'id': 1, 'price': 12.4}, 
 {'qty': 10, 'product': 'Item 2', 'id': 2, 'price': 7.5}, 
 {'qty': 7, 'product': 'Item 3', 'id': 3, 'price': 18.0}]
```

---

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouper = itemgetter("id", "product", "price")
result = []
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(purchases, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["id", "product", "price"], key))
    temp_dict["qty"] = sum(item["qty"] for item in grp)
    result.append(temp_dict)

print(result)
[{'qty': 12, 'product': 'Item 1', 'id': 1, 'price': 12.4}, 
 {'qty': 10, 'product': 'Item 2', 'id': 2, 'price': 7.5}, 
 {'qty': 7, 'product': 'Item 3', 'id': 3, 'price': 18}]
```

EDIT by comment:

```
purchases = [
   { 
       'id': 1, 'product': { 'id': 1, 'name': 'item 1' }, 'price': 12.4, 'qty' : 4
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 1, 'product': { 'id': 1, 'name': 'item 2' }, 'price': 12.4, 'qty' : 8
   },
   { 
       'id': 2, 'product':{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'item 3' }, 'price': 7.5, 'qty': 10
   }, 
   { 
       'id': 3, 'product': { 'id': 3, 'name': 'item 4' }, 'price': 18, 'qty': 7
   }
]
```

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(purchases)
print (df)
   id  price  product.id product.name  qty
0   1   12.4           1       item 1    4
1   1   12.4           1       item 2    8
2   2    7.5           2       item 3   10
3   3   18.0           3       item 4    7

print (df.groupby(['id','product.id', 'price'], as_index=False)['qty'].sum()
         .to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'qty': 12.0, 'price': 12.4, 'id': 1.0, 'product.id': 1.0}, 
 {'qty': 10.0, 'price': 7.5, 'id': 2.0, 'product.id': 2.0}, 
 {'qty': 7.0, 'price': 18.0, 'id': 3.0, 'product.id': 3.0}]
```

Comment: It is for return `DataFrame` from `groupby`, if missing get `Series`

Comment: hey thanks for providing more than 1 groupedby that is what i needed.

Comment: may i ask another question?

Comment: sure, no problem.

Comment: what if the product is an object? `product : { 'id': 1, 'name': 'item 1' }` how can i group that by product.id?

Comment: It is more complicated, I have to test it. Give me a time.

Comment: it is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, not the most elegant, but easier to understand

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
some = [((x['id'], x['product'], x['price']), x['qty']) for x in purchases]
for x in some:
    c[x[0]] += x[1]

[{'id': k[0], 'product': k[1], 'price': k[2], 'qty': v} for k, v in c.items()]
```

And that i measured that solution with `groupby` solution of @jezrael

And `100000 loops, best of 3: 9.03 µs per loop` vs @jezrael's `100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop`

Comment: but the problem here we cant group anything by property

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab can you explain what do you mean my "cant group anything by property"?

Comment: example i want the distinct of product and price and the aggregate of qty

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yeah, i got it, not generic solution, totally agree.