# Python: summing up list of dictionaries with different keys and same values

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have the following list of dictionaries with different keys and values. Every dictionary has only one key-value pair.

```
[{'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'a':1}, {'b':2}]
```

I need the following output preferably using list/dict comprehension

```
[{'a': 2, 'b': 3}]
```

I had a look on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490738/how-to-sum-dict-elements), but wasn't lucky to figure it out.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: And you are looking for a list/dict comprehension specifically?

Comment: Yes, preferably

Comment: Does every `dict` contains exactly one key-value pair?

Comment: Yes, one key-value pair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum dict elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490738/how-to-sum-dict-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an answer in the question you linked to that works as is:

```
dict1 = [{'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'a':1}, {'b':2}]

final = {}
for d in dict1:
    for k in d.keys():
        final[k] = final.get(k,0) + d[k]

print (final)
```

Yields:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [{'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'a':1}, {'b':2}]

c = Counter()

for dct in lst: 
    c.update(dct)

print(c)
# Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2})
```

Comment: `Counter.update` would do a good job here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491086/1388292

Comment: @JacquesGaudin how on earth could i have missed that?! thanks! updated.

Answer (score 2):

**This can be done in a single line without any imports using some clever reducing**

To understand how this works, you have to understand how [reduce](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce) works. Essentially, it allows you define an operation which takes two element from the list and reduces them down to a single element. It then applies this operation recursively to your list until the list has been reduced to a single element. Here is the one-line version:

```
dict1 = [{'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'a':1}, {'b':2}]

print(reduce(lambda a, b: {k: a.setdefault(k, 0) + b.setdefault(k, 0) for k in set(a.keys()).union(b.keys())}, dict1))
```

In this case, the operation is defined as:

```
lambda a, b: 
        {k: a.setdefault(k, 0) + b.setdefault(k, 0) for k in (set(a.keys()).union(b.keys()))}
```

Which can also be expressed as:

```
# a and b are two elements from the list. In this case they are dictionaries
def combine_dicts(a, b):
    output = {}
    for k in set(a.keys()).union(b.keys()): # the union of the keys in a and b
        output[k] = a.setdefault(k, 0) + b.setdefault(k, 0)
        # dict.setdefault returns the provided value if the key doesn't exist
    return output
```

When this operation is applied to your list with reduce, you get the desired output:

```
>>> {'b': 3, 'a': 2}
```