# Counter in module typing in python3 ignore the items with value 0

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I want to count the value of the key dictionary.
I understood Counter in typing module ignore the element with value 0. The code is:

```
from functools import reduce
from typing import Counter

pen={'age':0, 'cost':10}
bottle={'age':0,'cost':30}
all = [pen, bottle]
reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, (Counter(item) for item in all))
```

The output is {'cost':40} and Counter ignores the element with count 0. I want the output is {'cost':40, 'age':0}.
There are other ways to count the value of keys in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Hussain Hassam

Based on [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068744/add-counters-keeping-zero-values) I edit code based on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068744/add-counters-keeping-zero-values):

```
from functools import reduce
from typing import Counter

pen={'age':0, 'cost':10}
bottle={'age':0,'cost':30}
all = [pen, bottle]
reduce(lambda a, b: a.update(b) or a, all, Counter())
```