# Sorting dictionary - functools.reduce ignores negative values?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary like below:

```
d = [{152: 1}, {151: 3}, {152: 4}, {153: 5}, {153: 10}, {154: -0.1}]
```

I want to sort them like below:

```
{151: 3, 152: 5, 153: 15, 154: -0.1}
```

I tried the below by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491086/14348358) ...

```
sorted = dict(functools.reduce(operator.add, map(collections.Counter, d)))
```

The output I got is :

```
{151: 3, 152: 5, 153: 15}
```

I do not understand why `functools.reduce(operator.add, )` removes the `{154: -0.1}`. Isn't `operator.add` just [a plain summation method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)?

> operator.add(a, b)
> operator.**add**(a, b)
> Return a + b, for a and b numbers.

**Questions**

- What could be the workaround to achieve the desired output?
- Why does `functools.reduce(operator.add, )` remove the negative value?

Comment: d is not a dict but a lit of dicts

Answer (score 1):

The Counter class is designed for positive counts so -0.1 is treated as 0 by its addition method (as would any other negative result).  You could do this using a loop and a regular dictionary (no library needed):

```
dicts = [{152: 1}, {151: 3}, {152: 4}, {153: 5}, {153: 10}, {154: -0.1}]

r = dict()
for d in dicts:
    r.update({k:r.get(k,0)+v for k,v in d.items()})

print(r)
{152: 5, 151: 3, 153: 15, 154: -0.1}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for Counter states that *Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less*

Comment: And to clarify from OP's question: "Why does functools.reduce(operator.add, ) remove the negative value?"
It's not that functools.reduce(operator.add, ...) "removes" the negative value; rather, when one Counter object is added to another Counter object (in this case via `functools.reduce`), the resulting Counter object will not contain any key, value pairs where the value would be less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

A `pandas` solution

```py
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>d = [{152: 1}, {151: 3}, {152: 4}, {153: 5}, {153: 10}, {154: -0.1}]
>>>pd.DataFrame(d).sum().to_dict()
{152: 5.0, 151: 3.0, 153: 15.0, 154: -0.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator.add` is a plain summation method, please see its source code: [operator.add](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/operator.py#L77)

---

Why does `functools.reduce(operator.add, )` remove the negative value?

Your one-line code is equivalent to `Counter({152: 1}) + Counter({151: 3}) + Counter({152: 4}) + Counter({153: 5}) + Counter({153: 10}) + Counter({154: -0.1})`

However, the `add` method for `Counter` will remove negative values, check its source: [counter-add](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L810)

Thus, the value for key `154` will be ignored.

---

How to make your work done?

```
t = {}
for i in d:
    for k in i.keys():
        t[k] = t[k]+i[k] if k in t else i[k]
```